# Why doesn't the URL rewrite doesn't handle the non-WWW to www?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am using Apache server for URL redirects.

I'm making url redirects in `00_application.conf` of Apache at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk` in AWS

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/qqd [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/qqd/ [L,R=301]

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

The second RewriteCond in above code doesn't work.
But first RewriteCond does work.

Following example doesn't work either.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    . . .
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

I want non-WWW URLs to be redirected to www.example.com/qqd

Please help.

PS: When I do mywebsite.com without www, this is what I see
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWIqD.png

I am wondering, when I do mywebsite.com without www, whether that request is hitting my server (or Amazon Route 53 Hosted zone --> web server --> app sever).

I thought this might be an additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. 
Yep, My guess was right.

When I do www.example.com it hits my webserver --> URL reroute logic. 
But when I do example.com in browser, it doesn't hit my server at all.

I was getting 
https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-99c326b3c6af3d7101645af4a12516b9

We need to have an A record for both

`www.example.com` as well as
`example.com`

and make sure both point to web server where you have your URL redirect logic.

Good luck.